# output number is doubled

Tags: javascript, sum

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTotal(form, totalEl)
{
  var el, els = form.elements;
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i=0, num=els.length; i<num; ++i){
    el = els[i];

    if ('text' == el.type){ //&& /SumB/.test(el.name)
      sum += +el.value;
    }
    form.elements[totalEl].value = sum;
  }
}
</script>
```

If I use an alert I get the correct output but it fills the wrong value into "totalEl" You can test this on (fixed) It's the first block of checkboxes and textboxes!

Comment: If the total element is itself an element, are you also adding it to itself? Perhaps take the some of all the elements *except the last one*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTotal(form, totalEl)
{
  var el, els = form.elements;
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i=0, num=els.length; i<num; ++i){
    el = els[i];

    // Do not include totalEl
    if ('text' == el.type && el != form.elements[totalEl]) {
      sum += +el.value;
    }
  }
  form.elements[totalEl].value = sum;
}
</script>
```

If `totalEl` is an element of the form, then the `form.elements[totalEl].value = sum;` line must be outside the `for` loop, otherwise the value of `totalEl` itself will be included in the last calculation, resulting in a double sum.

Comment: Inside the loop it'll set it over and over,  but that's just inefficient, not the issue.

Comment: Then try to exclude the value of `totalEl` from the sum: `if ('text' == el.type && el != form.elements[totalEl]) ...`

Answer (score 0):

It'll add the value in the "sum" text element as well the way it's written right now. Use a class, or subtract the current total from the new total after adding, or just zero the element out before the loop.

As the other answer mentions, the part that sets the "sum" field shouldn't be in the loop, too.